# make flex-item honour width only if there is content

Tags: reactjs, css, flexbox

I want create a flex-item which takes a width of 33% of the container only if there is some content present as follows:

```
<FlexItem width='33%'> <Somedom /> </FlexItem>
```

Here, the `FlexItem` is a component that can take all flex properties as props and renders a div. Now, `Somedom` can render null in the dom in which case I want the `FlexItem` to take no width at all and allow the sibling div to fill the entire container.

I was wondering if there is any flex based arrangement which can help me achieve that. Further I have no good way of knowing if its going to render content or not. I don't want to move `FlexItem` component in `Somedom` as well.

Comment: Maybe via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: This works. Thanks. You can post it as an answer and I would accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @04FS suggestion of [:empty](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

You could do something as simple as this.

```css
.FlxRw {
  display: flex;
}
.Flx {
  flex:0 0 33%;
  background:#cdf;
}
.Flx:empty {
  flex:0 0 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="FlxRw">
  <div class="Flx"></div>
</div>

<div class="FlxRw">
  <div class="Flx">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="FlxRw">
  <div class="Flx"></div>
</div>
```